# Code-Outlook-Compiled Error

Tags: xcode, outlook

Below is my code for outlook...for some reason it is not accepting it?

```
Sub MakeMemo()
Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\users\mccjors\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\HPE_eMemo.oft")
newItem.Display
Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub

Sub MakeInvite()
Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\users\mccjors\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\HPE_evite.oft")
newItem.Display
Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub

Sub MakeNewsletter()
Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\users\mccjors\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\HPE_Newsletter.oft")
newItem.Display
Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on why it's making this error?

Comment: What is the error message you getting?

Comment: @Matthew Compile Error: Expected: end of statement